# MeshFunctions didn't behave as my expectation

Tags: plotting, intersection

```
Plot[{Tan[x], x Sin[x]}, {x, -8, 8}, MeshFunctions -> {Tan[#] - # 
Sin[#] &}, Mesh -> {{0.0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, 
PointSize[Large]]]
```

Just as the picture shows, there are some incorrect points around the intersection point.

[image: I want to put a red point on the lines' intersection, but it does't work.]

Answer (score 3):

When using `MeshFunctions`, it is often a good idea to reformulate your functions so that it is free of poles or other singularities:

```
Plot[{Tan[x], x Sin[x]}, {x, -8, 8}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#] - # Sin[2 #]/2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
     MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image: intersections]

Similar principles apply to the use of e.g. `FindRoot[]` for finding intersections.